# Cannot find the directory in a docker instanced deployed to AWS ECS?

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

My `Dockerfile` has the following line.

```
RUN useradd -r -m -d /app -s /bin/bash xyz
RUN usermod -a -G root xyz
RUN mkdir -p /app/xyz
WORKDIR /app
```

However, I couldn't find the directory `/app` after ssh to the docker instance? `ps -auwx` can see the program running from `/app/....`.

```
ssh -i /et/ssl/certs/....crt login@docker_instance_address

# in the ssh session
ls /app # No such file or directory
ps auwx | grep '...' # can see the programming launched by docker start
# shows /app/xyz/.....
```

---

I couldn't run `docker exec -it xyz /bin/bash` from the ECS cluster instance - permission denied.

Comment: What command are you running to verify this?

Comment: In the ssh session, I tried `ls /app` but it showed no such directory.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating this, with a complete Dockerfile, instructions on how to launch the container, and what you're connecting to?  It's unusual for the main container process to be an ssh daemon (though it happens); if you're connecting to the host running the containers, you won't see the per-container filesystems.